# CountryData fails for some tags and properties

Tags: curated-data, geography

The problem has gone, presumably resolved by WRI. See kirma's comment.

---

I'm using Mathematica 10.0.2 for Mac, and for the first time just tried `CountryData`.

Executing the first example in the documentation of `CountryData` is fine:

```
CountryData["France", "Population"]
```

but the second one fails:

```
CountryData["G8"]
```

with the following error messages:

> General::aofil: /Users/ME/Library/Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/CountryData-9.0.64/Data/CountryData.wdx already open as /Users/ME/Library/Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/CountryData-9.0.64/Data/CountryData.wdx. >>
>
> OpenWrite::noopen: Cannot open /Users/ME/Library/Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/CountryData-9.0.64/Data/CountryData.wdx. >>
>
> General::stream: $Failed is not a string, InputStream[ ], or OutputStream[ ]. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of General::stream will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> SetFileDate::nffil: File not found during SetFileDate[/Users/ME/Library/Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/CountryData-9.0.64/Data/CountryData.wdx,{2014,3,7,13,31,4}]. >>

<strike>What could possibly be the cause of this?</strike>

Do you have any suggestions for what I should try to restore the functionality of `CountryData`?

## Update

As reported in the comments, I've removed my previous ~/Library/Mathematica/Paclets/Temporary. Now `CountryData["G8"]` just gives me

```
$Failed
```

without anything else.

Comment: have you tried `RebuildPacletData[]`? I think that problem has already come up, there seems to be a problem when updating from v9 to v10 but I can't find the question for the moment...

Comment: Sadly that doesn't help...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem on my Mac with v10.0.2  Have you tried starting with a fresh kernel? Or restarting your Mac?

Comment: Are you still getting the same error messages? A brute force alternative to guarantee you have a clean state would be to delete all 9.x files/directories in Paclets/Repository and then do `RebuildPacletData`, but probably what I have in mind is not your problem...

Comment: I've also tried both restarting Mathematica and my computer, but still got the same error messages. Will now try deleting all 9.x paclet files. Where exactly are they though?

Comment: Sorry it's a stupid question. The error messages show where. There were only two subfolders in Paclets/Repository: PredictiveInterface-Mac-2.4.316 and WolframAutoUpdate-1.0.0. Strangely, all `CountryData-10.0.73xxxxxx.paclet` are in Paclets/Temporary, not CountryData-9.0.64...

Comment: Wait... that's a NINE... My Mathematica is still using CountryData-**9**.0.64 here. Interesting.

Comment: I've noticed that Mathematica creates the folder CountryData-9.0.64 in Paclets/Repository while executing `CountryData`, but the folder is deleted as soon as the error messages appear.

Comment: I've copied the folder CountryData-9.0.64 to examine its contents before it's deleted. CountryData.wdx is missing from CountryData-9.0.64/Data.

Comment: I've removed Paclets/Temporary. CountryData.wdx is now present in CountryData-9.0.64/Data. But executing `CountryData["G8"]` now just silently gives `$Failed` in the output then still deletes the folder CountryData-9.0.64! I tried `RebuildPacletData[]` again but still it didn't help.

Comment: 10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 4, 2014) - no problems at all

Comment: I think you should try to remove the content of Paclets/Repository but not the directory itself. Then before doing anything else do `RebuildPacletData[]`. After that try `CountryData` again, it should now download the matching paclet version which will take some time. If this does not work I'm out of ideas, I don't know about the stuff in Temporary, never touched that. On my system there is CountryData-10.0.73, 10.0.39 and the 9.0.64 that you also see. I don't know but would think that this could have to do with the fact that I'm still using version 9 and have been using 10.0.1 and 10.0.2...

Comment: I have had this problem on v10.1 and contacted WRI support after trying out all possible paclet remedies. The response wasn't exactly pleasing; I really feel they were trying to dodge around responsibility for the problem on their end. This was about two weeks ago for several days in succession - when I try it now it seems to work!

Comment: Thank you very much @kirma for urging WRI to solve this and taking time to tell me it now works. Indeed it now works on my machine too (clearly suggesting that the problem was on the server end in the first place).